# Add column values to a bar-plot next to plot names

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I have this dataframe:

```
structure(list(taxon = c("Bacteria 1", "Bacteria 2", 
"Bacteria 3", "Bacteria 4", "Bacteria 5", "Bacteria 6"), lfc_StatusChronic.ACST0. = c(0.88175957, 
0.88803574, 0.790947444, 1.319321361, 0.7176503, 0.758374253), 
    se_StatusChronic.ACST0. = c(0.439259504, 0.449835605, 0.369268494, 
    0.391714918, 0.27578621, 0.364036816), lfc_Time.fT1 = c(-0.021243562, 
    0.66196107, 0.334274258, -0.382520121, -0.005363874, -0.313304181
    ), se_Time.fT1 = c(0.312681188, 0.330173331, 0.301559494, 
    0.309355933, 0.293938402, 0.302957725), lfc_Time.fT2 = c(-1.092105655, 
    -0.083635974, -0.435405323, -1.221704783, -0.557850053, -0.734425087
    ), se_Time.fT2 = c(0.326565043, 0.344533883, 0.31544836, 
    0.323423323, 0.307225241, 0.317023725), lfc_Time.fT3 = c(-0.684898535, 
    0.007779894, -0.661494348, -0.765693993, -0.294827229, -1.082174069
    ), se_Time.fT3 = c(0.324919486, 0.342422134, 0.314578177, 
    0.322254678, 0.305999846, 0.316331693), lfc_Time.fT4 = c(-1.038613852, 
    -0.159777157, -0.172345815, -0.691220321, -0.444048742, -1.062300665
    ), se_Time.fT4 = c(0.319416657, 0.336513636, 0.309526757, 
    0.316959694, 0.300928605, 0.311343927), lfc_Time.fT5 = c(-0.714954683, 
    0.081376697, -0.621676699, -0.483698623, -0.339094441, -0.718106519
    ), se_Time.fT5 = c(0.317230276, 0.334106044, 0.307553106, 
    0.314893819, 0.298943665, 0.309379791), pvalue = c(0.0447, 
    0.0484, 0.0322, 8e-04, 0.0093, 0.0372)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

and I have done a bar plot like this:

```
taxonFC1 %>%
  rename(lfc_time.fT0 = lfc_StatusChronic.ACST0., 
         se_Time.fT0 = se_StatusChronic.ACST0.) %>%
  pivot_longer(-taxon, names_pattern="(.*)_[Tt]ime\\.f(.*)", 
               names_to = c(".value", "time")) %>% 
   ggplot(aes(x = time, y = lfc, ymin = lfc - se, ymax = lfc + se, fill = taxon)) +
   geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
   geom_errorbar(width=.4) + 
   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
   scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired") + 
    xlab("") +
    ylab("LogFC") +
    facet_wrap(~taxon, ncol=3) + 
    ggtitle("9 taxas") +
    scale_x_discrete(labels = c("ACs & Chronic", "T1 Vs T0", "T2 Vs T0", "T3 Vs T0", "T4 Vs T0", "T5 Vs T0"))
```

As you can see, the last column of the dataframe contains the p-values, I would like to put this values next to the bacteria name (e.g. Bacteria 1 (p-value = 0.0093)), but not in the legend.
And if it is possible to sort them from more significative (p<0.05).

I have tried using this:

```
taxonFC1$taxon <- paste(taxonFC1$taxon, "(p-value =", taxonFC1[,ncol(taxonFC1)], ")", sep = " ")
```

but it shows also in the legend.

Any help is more than welcome
Thanks!!

Comment: Do you want to still keep the legend and if so what do you want it to contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change plot order we add factor levels, to extract bacteria names we do some character string manipulation.

```
taxonFC1$taxon <- paste(taxonFC1$taxon, "(p-value =", taxonFC1[,ncol(taxonFC1)], ")", sep = " ")
legendcolors <- RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(6,'Paired')
taxonFC1 %>% arrange(pvalue) %>% 
  rename(lfc_time.fT0 = lfc_StatusChronic.ACST0., 
         se_Time.fT0 = se_StatusChronic.ACST0.) %>%
  pivot_longer(-taxon, names_pattern="(.*)_[Tt]ime\\.f(.*)", 
               names_to = c(".value", "time")) %>% 
  na.omit() %>% # Be careful this removes all rows with ANY NA's
  mutate(legend_labels=substr(taxon,1,unlist(gregexpr('p-value', taxon))[2]-2),#str_locate(taxon,"p-value = ")[1,1]-2),
         pval = substr(taxon,str_locate(taxon,"p-value = ")[1,2]+1,str_locate(taxon,"p-value = ")[1,2]+6),
         # testlabel=substr(taxon,1,str_locate(taxon,' ')[1,1]))
         porder=factor(taxon, levels = c("Bacteria 4 (p-value = 8e-04 )","Bacteria 5 (p-value = 0.0093 )",
                                                    "Bacteria 3 (p-value = 0.0322 )","Bacteria 6 (p-value = 0.0372 )",
                                                    "Bacteria 1 (p-value = 0.0447 )","Bacteria 2 (p-value = 0.0484 )"))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = lfc, ymin = lfc - se, ymax = lfc + se, fill = legend_labels)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_errorbar(width=.4) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  # scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired") + 
  xlab("") +
  ylab("LogFC") +
  facet_wrap(~porder, ncol=3, ) + 
  ggtitle("9 taxas") +
  scale_x_discrete() +
  scale_fill_manual(name="Bacteria Name",
                    values = legendcolors)
```

[image]

Comment: It is almost this @dandrews. The taxon label should be the bacteria names, but without the p-value, and I've tried to order from the most significative (lowest value). Also I've notice there is a 7th column named "NA", it shouldn't be there

Comment: How to you mean "from the most significant"? Do you want the highest significance in the upper left and lowest in the lower right?

Comment: yes, exactly that

Comment: Should have used `str_locate`, should work now, moving on to order

Comment: Yes, that is, I have added the labels to ```scale_x_discrete()```, but I see that the "Bacteria Name" is not complete, do you know why?

Comment: I added the plot I'm getting is yours the same? If so I'm not sure what you mean by not complete?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252538/discussion-between-dandrews-and-windsur).